# How to set up a socket for UDP multicast with 2 network cards?

Tags: c#, sockets, mono, multicast, multicastsocket

this problem like [How to set up a socket for UDP multicast with 2 network cards present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361854/how-to-set-up-a-socket-for-udp-multicast-with-2-network-cards-present?rq=1), but this is for C++, But I am in mono, So I want to know how to do this in C#.

I use follow code :

```
this.m_DhcpSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
this.m_DhcpSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(m_DhcpInterface.GetIPProperties().MulticastAddresses.FirstOrDefault().Address, DhcpPort));
```

but there is no Multicast address under Linux.

Can anybody help me?