# Receiving multicast data on RHEL 7 using c++

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, multicast, rhel

I am trying to receive multicast UDP data on a network interface on RHEL 7.2

So, about my setup:
  NIC: Intel X540
    IP: 192.168.42.100
  Distro: RHEL 7.2
  Multicast Address: 224.5.6.7
  Port: 2002
  Interface name: ens4f1

I have 2 interfaces open, the 1 Gbit on the Mobo and one of the 10 Gbit on the intel card.

Like many other posts, I have data coming in and visible on both wireshark and tcpdump but my recvfrom call just hangs. My code is a copy of a similar problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361854/how-to-set-up-a-socket-for-udp-multicast-with-2-network-cards-present), which appears to be working for the OP.

**Notes:**

1) I run my code as root

2) I have tried to change the rp_filter in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/ens4f1/rp_filter to 0. No change

3) Disabling SELinux did not change anything

4) Wireshark and tcpdump shows the data just fine. Dump shown below

```
[@localhost ~]$ sudo tcpdump -c 5 -i ens4f1 -v
tcpdump: listening on ens4f1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
15:43:57.368470 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 6526, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 7996)
    192.168.42.44.62111 > 224.5.6.7.globe: UDP, length 7968
15:43:57.368477 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 6526, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 316)
    192.168.42.44.62111 > 224.5.6.7.globe: UDP, length 288
15:43:57.368869 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 6526, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 7996)
    192.168.42.44.62111 > 224.5.6.7.globe: UDP, length 7968
15:43:57.368878 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 6526, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 316)
    192.168.42.44.62111 > 224.5.6.7.globe: UDP, length 288
15:43:57.369264 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 6526, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 7996)
    192.168.42.44.62111 > 224.5.6.7.globe: UDP, length 7968
5 packets captured
46 packets received by filter
9 packets dropped by kernel
```

**Copy of code**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define HELLO_PORT 2002
#define HELLO_GROUP "224.5.6.7"
#define MSGBUFSIZE 10000

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string source_iface("192.168.42.100");
    string group(HELLO_GROUP);
    int port(HELLO_PORT);

    cout << "group: " << group << " port: " << port << " source_iface: " << source_iface << endl;

    int fd;
    if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    u_int yes = 1;
    if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Reusing ADDR failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr =  (group.empty() ?
                            htonl(INADDR_ANY) :
                            inet_addr(group.c_str()));

    if (bind(fd,(struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct ip_mreq mreq;
    mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(group.c_str());
    mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = (source_iface.empty() ? htonl(INADDR_ANY) : inet_addr(source_iface.c_str()));

    if (setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0)
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(1);
    }

    socklen_t addrlen;
    int nbytes;
    char msgbuf[MSGBUFSIZE];

    while (1)
    {
        memset(&msgbuf, 0, MSGBUFSIZE);

        addrlen = sizeof(addr);
        if ((nbytes = recvfrom(fd, msgbuf, MSGBUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addrlen)) < 0)
        {
            perror("recvfrom");
            exit(1);
        }
        cout.write(msgbuf, nbytes);
        cout.flush();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

All help and suggestions are most welcome

Thanks

Henrik

Comment: What does `netstat -an` and `netstat -ng` show?

Comment: The -ng shows that my interface correctly joins the multicast group. I'm unable to interpret the -an output, but I can't find anything that e.g. looks like the path to my program if that is expected. I can't give you a printout since I can't reach the computer before I get back to work monday.

Comment: The output of `netstat -an` should tell you the IP/port you're connected to.  There should be an entry for udp with IP 224.5.6.7 port 2002.

Comment: I have a line saying: "udp 0 0 224.5.6.7:2002 0.0.0.0:*", but another line says established, and mine does not

Comment: Note: I can receive data from the system using both mcsender (found here: http://troglobit.com/smcroute.html) and my own code where I simply send data to the multicast IP with loopback enabled. Data from outside does not show however.       P.S. it is quite easy to receive on a standard windows 8.1 machine, but the socket interface is quite different and maybe setup as well.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that it is probably the firewall creating problems for me. I can now get data on 1 interface but not the other. Closing question and posting another one

Comment: I know this is old, but I've seen a lot of networking code where people `htonl(INADDR_ANY)`. I believe this is wrong, since the macros should be expected to provide network order, just like the (deprecated) `inet_addr` call does. Fortunately, the value of `INADDR_ANY` is `0xFFFF` so byte-swapping has no effect, harmful or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with the firewalld in RHEL 7. Creating a rule described here https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1587673 solved it for one interface, but not both. Will repost another question for that if I don't solve it.

EDIT:
The culprit for getting both running at the same time was setting the rp_filter value to 2 for all interfaces. Setting it for only 1 does not do anything if the 'all' category is still 1.

```
    net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2
```

This can be done by creating a file at /etc/sysctl.d/multicast.conf or using a "sysctl -w" call.